# Change all blank spaces say "null", then change back

Tags: excel, null, vba

I'm building a table in VBA to upload to SQL. I have thousands of rows and thousands of results that don't need updating, i.e. null values. In the table, they are left blank, but for uploading purposes I want all of them to change to say "null". Then after the upload, I want them to go back to being blank. I have read online that something like this should work:

```vb
Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="Null", LookAt:=xlPart, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I think the above could be what I'm looking for -- but I want to be able to specify that I only want to apply it to columns `K-N`. I'm aware there is the find and replace option in Excel, but as there are so many cells, Excel breaks down.

Comment: `wdReplaceAll` and `wdFindContinue` are MS word constants - if you're running this in Excel then these will not work.

Comment: The term, `building a table in VBA` is not clear.  What does it mean?

Comment: Ive updated the question, I think the following code is the answer. I think it is probably quite a simple solution I'm looking for

Comment: Something along the lines of:.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="Null", LookAt:=xlPart, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
   ReplaceFormat:=False

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("K2:N11000").Replace What:="", Replacement:="Null", LookAt:=xlPart, _
   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
   ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Was simple, as I imagined. thanks anyway